# What may cause huge latency while ssh

Tags: centos, ssh, latency

I'm working on a local Windows and three remote CentOS7 Linux servers. The three servers are under the same gateway. The IPs of the three sesrvers are: 170.35.31.104, 170.35.31.105, 170.35.31.106.

I used MobaXterm (free version) to ssh my remote servers.

When I `ssh tester@170.35.31.105` and `ssh tester@170.35.31.106`, it works fine.

But when I `ssh tester@170.35.31.104`, I will get a huge latency:
after `ssh tester@170.35.31.104`, about 30 seconds later, I get a sentence: `Authorized users only. All activities may be monitored and reported.`. Then after about 5 more seconds later, I will login successfully.

I've tested `ssh tester@170.35.31.104` many times many days, I always need to wait about 35 seconds after typing `ssh tester@170.35.31.104`.

I really want to know what causes the huge latency.

Any idea?

BTW, `ssh -V` on the three servers gives me the same output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Comment: Is DNS set up on the system?  Have you tried disabling GSSAPIAuthentication?

Comment: @jsbillings  disabling GSSAPIAuthentication changed nothing.

Comment: @jsbillings In fact, my remote servers have no DNS because there is no DNS server.

Comment: @jsbillings  I just found that `/etc/resolv.conf` on `170.35.31.104` is not empty but `etc/resolv.conf` on the other machines are empty.

Comment: You have to add `UseDNS no` in sshd_config and/or you are firewalling ICMP type 3

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   Yes! `UseDNS no` killed the latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

,As you are ssh'ing using IP addresses, in the client side, there is no DNS resolution involved, so the culprit is surely, the `useDNS` option in `sshd_config` on the server side.

I would advise also watching out for other services, that might try to resolve DNS for logging/accepting requests, or in alternative, setting up internal DNS services. e.g. see [this for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/dns-caveats.html) and [another one for Apache](http://www.ecometer.org/rules/disable-apaches-dns-lookup.html), or [yet another one for syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.23/administration-guide/use-dns), or [a related MySQL one](https://nixcp.com/skip-name-resolve/) for examples of possible issues in services and/or their configuration files.

As far as I am aware, the [default in 7.4 has been changed to `useDNS no`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1478175)  ; previously it was `useDNS yes`. So that has to been taken in consideration when dealing with different versions of the OpenSSH server.

Generally, as strange issues might crop up with DNS absence in services/applications (mis)configurations, I prefer to have some kind of DNS service present, even it is a simple `dnsmasq` drinking from `/etc/hosts`, answering in ports 53/UDP and 53/TCP.